# How to get a new pandas data frame column with cluster groups using scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I am new to scikit-learn. I have a pandas DataFrame with 1 column containing text that I want to cluster.
As an end result I would like to have my dataframe showing an extra column with the cluster group it belongs to, for each row.
My DF looks like this:

```
event_date,event_desc,event_url
2020-05-28 07:03:00,Roche’s OCREVUS (ocrelizumab) shorter 2-hour infusion time approved in Europe,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-28b.htm
2020-05-28 07:00:00,Roche initiates phase III clinical trial of Actemra/RoActemra plus remdesivir in hospitalised patients with severe COVID-19 pneumonia,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-28.htm
2020-05-27 07:00:00,Roche’s Port Delivery System with ranibizumab shows positive phase III results in neovascular age-related macular degeneration,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-27.htm
2020-05-25 15:00:00,Reminder: Invitation to Roche’s virtual event on key oncology data presented at ASCO 2020,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-25.htm
2020-05-22 07:03:00,Roche acquires Stratos Genomics to further develop DNA based sequencing for diagnostic use,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-22b.htm
2020-05-22 07:00:00,New longer-term data reinforce safety of Roche’s satralizumab in adults and adolescents with neuromyelitis optica spectrum disorder,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-22.htm
2020-05-19 07:00:00,FDA approves Roche’s Tecentriq as a first-line monotherapy for certain people with metastatic non-small cell lung cancer,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-19.htm
2020-05-15 07:00:00,Roche launches new blood gas digital solution designed to improve patient care,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-15.htm
2020-05-14 07:00:00,Roche to present first clinical data on novel anti-TIGIT cancer immunotherapy tiragolumab at ASCO,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-14.htm
2020-05-11 14:15:00,A formative figure in the company's history: Roche Honorary Chairman Fritz Gerber dies at the age of 91,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-11c.htm
2020-05-11 07:00:00,Changes to the Roche Enlarged Corporate Executive Committee,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-11.htm
2020-05-07 07:00:00,New data at the ASCO20 Virtual Scientific Program reflects Roche’s commitment to accelerating progress in cancer care,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-07.htm
2020-05-06 15:00:00,Invitation to Roche’s virtual event on key oncology data presented at ASCO 2020,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-06.htm
2020-05-03 04:15:00,Roche’s COVID-19 antibody test receives FDA Emergency Use Authorization and is available in markets accepting the CE mark,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-05-03.htm
2020-04-30 14:00:00,Reminder: Invitation to Roche’s Virtual Event “Digital technology and advanced analytics in Roche”,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-04-30.htm
2020-04-28 07:03:00,New 6-year data for Roche’s OCREVUS (ocrelizumab) show earlier treatment initiation nearly halves risk of needing walking aid in relapsing multiple sclerosis,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-04-28b.htm
2020-04-28 07:00:00,Roche’s risdiplam shows significant improvement in survival and motor milestones in infants with Type 1 spinal muscular atrophy (SMA),https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-04-28.htm
2020-04-24 17:35:00,Positive Results from the Phase III SAkuraStar Study for Satralizumab in NMOSD Published in The Lancet Neurology,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-04-24.htm
2020-04-22 07:00:00,"First quarter with 2% growth in Swiss francs, 7% at constant exchange rates",https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-04-22.htm
2020-04-21 14:00:00,Reminder: Invitation to Roche’s live audio webcast on new AAN 2020 data ,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-04-21b.htm
2020-04-21 07:00:00,Roche receives FDA approval for cobas HPV test for use on the cobas 6800/8800 Systems to identify women at risk for cervical cancer,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-04-21.htm
2020-04-20 07:00:00,US FDA and EMA accept applications for Roche’s OCREVUS (ocrelizumab) shorter 2-hour infusion time,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-04-20.htm
2020-04-17 07:00:00,Roche develops new serology test to detect COVID-19 antibodies,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-04-17.htm
2020-04-15 10:00:00,Reminder: Invitation to Roche’s First Quarter Sales 2020 Audio Webcast and Conference Call,https://www.roche.com/investors/updates/inv-update-2020-04-15b.htm
```

I run the clustering with column `event_desc`

So far I use the following code from [useful link](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/kmeans-text-clustering/):

```
    import pandas as pd

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    my_csv_file_name = 'temp.csv'
    result_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_name, sep=',', parse_dates=['event_date'],
                            dtype={'event_desc': pd.StringDtype(), 'event_url': pd.StringDtype()})


    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(result_df['event_desc'])
    true_k = 10
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
    model.fit(X)

    print("Top terms per cluster:")
    order_centroids = model.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]
    terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    for i in range(true_k):
        print("Cluster %d:" % i),
        for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
            print(' %s' % terms[ind]),

    print("Prediction")

    Y = vectorizer.transform(["chrome browser to open."])
    prediction = model.predict(Y)
    print(prediction)
```

It prints "grouped" keywords by cluster, but I would like to associate each cluster with its own row: meaning that the initial dataframe would have an extra column `cluster_group` with numbers between 0 to 9  corresponding to the cluster group it belongs to (I choose 10 groups-the actual csv is more than 3000 rows). Any idea of how to do that?
Thanks a lot. best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cluster groups are stored in the `labels_` attribute of your `model` object, i.e. `model.labels_` returns an array where each element contains the cluster group of each row in your data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

my_csv_file_name = 'temp.csv'
result_df = pd.read_csv(my_csv_file_name, sep=',', parse_dates=['event_date'],
dtype={'event_desc': pd.StringDtype(), 'event_url': pd.StringDtype()})

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(result_df['event_desc'])

true_k = 10
model = KMeans(n_clusters=true_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=100, n_init=1)
model.fit(X)

# extract the cluster groups
result_df['cluster_group'] = model.labels_

print(result_df['cluster_group'].sort_values().unique())
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```